# Clojure int to char (e.g. 1 to \1)

Tags: clojure

Is their a way in Clojure to go from an int to that int as a character, e.g. 1 to \1 ?

I have a string `s` and I want to parse out the digits that match a number `n` (n will always be 0 to 9)

e.g.

```
 (let [n 1]
     (filter #(= ??? %) "123123123"))
```

Where ??? would n as \n, e.g. would return "111"

Or maybe there is a better way to filter a string to only instance of a single digit?

Comment: Heads up: this will return `(\1 \1 \1)` - you would have to join that again to get `"111"`

Comment: @cfrick, that's actually fine. I just want the count of how many times that digit appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "java" way:

```clj
user=> (Character/forDigit 1 10) ; number and radix
\1
```

The "calculaty" way (add the int of `\0` to it and then back to char):

```clj
user=> (char (+ 1 (int \0)))
\1
```

Answer (score 4):

And as usual in Clojure, there's always a `reduce` one-line to solve the original problem: "I just want the count of how many times that digit appears."

```
(reduce (fn [m ch] (update m ch (fnil inc 0))) {} "123123123")
==> {\1 3, \2 3, \3 3}
```

A lot to unpack here, if you are new to Clojure.
Reduce is used to iterate over the String, counting occurrences of each character and storing it in a map.

From inner to outer:

`(fnil inc 0)` returns a function that runs `inc` with any argument provided. However, if the argument is nil, it will replace it with 0 instead. This is perfect for adding a new entry to the map.

`update` is used to look up an existing key `ch` in `m` and calculate a new value (by calling the function returned by `(fnil inc 0`)), i.e. if the `ch` is not in `m` this will run `(inc 0) => 1`, if `ch` is in `m` it will return the incremented counter.

`(fn [m ch] ...)` is the reducing function.
This is the most difficult part to understand. It takes two parameters.
The first is the last return value of this function (generated by an earlier iteration) or if it is the first time this function runs, the initial value provided: `{}` (there's also a third way to call reduce, see `(doc reduce)`)

The second argument `ch` is the current character in the String provided (since String is a CharSequence and counts as a collection).

So the reducing function is called for each character and we just return the current map with an updated count for each character, starting with `{}`.

Comment: and since counting occurrences is needed often, there's a standard fn for it: `frequencies`

Comment: Thank you! That's a wonderful explanation. Of course, frequencies! I forget this function exists all the time!

Comment: I really like for the actual task `((frequencies "111223") \1 0)`